# Coerce list to numeric in R "Existing data has XXX rows, Assigned data has YYYY rows"

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyverse, transformation

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
dput(head(df))
```

output here: https://pastebin.com/J84Eg6XD

```
head(df)
  council_name year No_candidates elected_C pre.post          Period co.ming.tonn
1         Adur 2006            38        12        0 Apr 06 - Jun 06        97.36
2         Adur 2006            38        12        0 Jul 06 - Sep 06        100.6
3         Adur 2006            38        12        0 Oct 06 - Dec 06       103.73
4         Adur 2008            61        16        0 Jan 08 - Mar 08         1495
5         Adur 2008            61        16        0 Apr 08 - Jun 08      1554.71
6         Adur 2008            61        16        0 Jul 08 - Sep 08      1568.94
```

But co.ming.tonn is a list.
What I'm trying to do is to transform the value "NULL" in this list into NAs and turn the list into a numeric. But I keep on getting the same errors.
For instances, I tried this:

```
df[df$co.ming.tonn == "NULL"] <- NA
df$co.ming.tonn <- as.numeric(unlist(df$co.ming.tonn))
```

And this:

```
df$co.ming.tonn <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df$co.ming.tonn)))
```

And I keep on getting this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, co.ming.tonn, value = c(97.36, 100.6,  : 
  replacement has 5260 rows, data has 5064
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok i think you have a weird structure. ```check = sapply(df$co.ming.tonn,length)>1 ; df[check,]``` see what are these entries. these rows have more than 1 entry, hence if you unlist, it will be longer

Comment: `head(df)` seems not to include any rows that display the feature causing you trouble.  When you say "transform to NULL", do you mean replace lists which are NULL with NA or replace elemnts in lists which have the value NULL with the value NA?  And does "turn the list into a numeric" mean convert to a list of numerics, or convert the list to a numeric?

Comment: @Limey sorry for not being clear.
When I say "transform to NUL" I mean  replace elements in lists which have the value NULL with the value NA
When I say "turn the list into a numeric" I mean convert the list to a numeric

Comment: OK.  Please do as @StupidWolf suggests and, if that doesn't make it clear what is going on, post the results of `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df))`, to give us a reasonably sized set of test data which demonstrates the problem you have.

Comment: Not clear which is the problem without a reproducible example. However, consider the `is.null` function to check whether an object is `NULL`.

Comment: @nicola the output of dput(head(df)) is here: https://pastebin.com/J84Eg6XD and also included in the issue's description

Comment: @StupidWolf the output of dput(head(df)) is here: pastebin.com/J84Eg6XD, and in the description above

Comment: Can you post the `dput` code here? If the `head` of `dput` is too big can you select only relevant columns and then share the `dput` ?

Comment: @AntVal, you have a data.frame or tibble that looks seriously wrong. Most likely some of your entries have 5 values. Did you read the file in correctly and can you provide a link to the original file